# scale down images with timthumb through adding typoscript to templavoila (data processing)

Tags: mobile, typo3, image-scaling, typoscript

I want to have two different image sizes: One for the normal browser and one for the mobile version. I thought I could use timthumb to resize the image.

Therefore I mapped in Templavoila an `Image field, fixed W+H` to an `<img src="xx" />`. Under `Data processing` I want to enter my Typoscript code. With this code I want to have another representation (scaled image).

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.XY = 1328,768
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
10.file.maxW = 2000
10.file.minW = 1000
10.file.maxH = 1000
10.file.minH = 700

[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|mobileversion=1]
20 = RECORDS
20.source.current = 1
20.tables = tt_content
20.stdWrap.wrap = <img src="fileadmin/templates/php_scripts/timthumb.php?src=|&w=600" />
20.stdWrap.required = 1*
[global]
```

But I always get the picture from the normal version. I tried to use the session variable and I also tried to use a user function. Even if I remove this condition the output is always the same... (big picture). What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 is able to resize your images out of the box. You do not need an additional script.

Put this in your Main-Template, where page.10 < plugin.tx_templavoila is defined:
    page.1 = LOAD_REGISTER
    page.1.mobileversion = 0

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|mobileversion=1]
  page.1.mobileversion = 1
[end]
```

Change your code:

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.XY = 1328,768
10.file.width = 1000
10.file.width.override = 500
10.file.width.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:mobileversion 
10.file.height = 1000
10.file.height.override = 500
10.file.height.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:mobileversion 
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
[...snip...]
```

For sure untested, but it should work even with TemplaVoila.

If you are using GIFBUILDER.IMAGE-Object (because you are using `10.file.XY`) you need to change your code like this:

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.XY = 1328,768
10.file.XY.override = 600,300
10.file.XY.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:mobileversion 
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
[...snip...]
```

But i guess, you mixed up [GIFBUILDER.IMAGE](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/8/) and [IMAGE](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/7/#id2634906).

Comment: Like it! Way more efficient than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

The below post from Dmitry Dulopev whilst a couple of years old now talks about how you can use Templa Voilla to add a mobile template as well.  Is this what you were after?

http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/04/creating-mobile-version-of-web-site.html

Comment: I already took this as basis for the mobile site. In one of my fields I'm taking the background image and map it to my mobile template. This image is for the normal browser and therefore big. Now I want instruct Templavoila to scale down the images (in my case with timthumb). But I can't get the typoscript working.

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of conditions (`[global]` etc.) don't yet work in TV data structures.

But you might be able to work your way around that using constants that you "inject" into the datastructure in combination with `stdWrap` conditions.

You can set TV constants in your regular TypoScript setup like that:

```
plugin.tx_templavoila_pi1.TSconst.ismobile = hellno
```

Here you can also use conditions, of course:

```
plugin.tx_templavoila_pi1.TSconst.ismobile = hellno
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|mobileversion=1]
plugin.tx_templavoila_pi1.TSconst.ismobile = yo
[global]
```

Now, in the TypoScript data processing of your TV field, you can do this:

```
10 = COA

10.10 = IMAGE
10.10 {
    # Your regular image

    stdWrap.if {
        value = {$TSconst.ismobile}
        equals = hellno
    }
}

10.20 = IMAGE
10.20 {
    # Image for mobile version

    stdWrap.if {
        value = {$TSconst.ismobile}
        equals = yo
    }
}
```

A few notes/questions:

- I'm not sure, `20` even gets processed in a TV field. I think it only looks for `10`.
- Why do you use timthumb at all? Why not another `IMAGE` cObject?
- Then, have a look at [`IMG_RESOURCE`](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/IMG_RESOURCE). It lets you work with just the image URL instead of the whole element tag. Later it might be easier to wrap your head around that than with the `RECORDS` stuff you have there.

**Disclaimer**: Haven't tested the above, so beware of typos or things like that. (I of course used the method in projects.)